# Closed form of $\sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j} (-1)^{k-j} j^b$ where $k,b$ are positive integers.

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am wondering about the closed form (if it exists) of $$\sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j} (-1)^{k-j} j^b$$ where $k,b$ are positive integers. I know it is equal to $0$ when $b<k$ and the sum is equal to $k!$ when $b=k$. However, I am at a complete loss as to what it equals when $b>k$. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a closed form

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}{k \choose j} j^b = k! \left\{\begin{matrix} b \\ k \end{matrix}\right\},  $$

where $ \left\{\begin{matrix} b \\ k \end{matrix}\right\} $ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: @Suugaku: You are welcome. By the way, it did not let you to accept the answer in the beginning. Why is that?

Comment: I think one has to wait a certain amount of time to accept an answer. It said something along the lines of having "to wait 45 seconds" until being able to accept.